# Page with chart.js charts truncates first few pixels of charts on left side of window

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using angular-chart and charts.js to draw a set of charts on the page.  I'm finding that my current layout ends up cutting off the first few pixels on the left side, if a chart is drawn on the left side.  I'm currently viewing this on Firefox.

Here's my current container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="dataCenterData in last30MinutesDataCenterDataList">
            <div class="row col-md-3">
                <canvas id="last30Minutes-chart-{{dataCenterData.dataCenter}}"
                        class="chart chart-line"
                        chart-data="dataCenterData.data"
                        chart-labels="dataCenterData.labels"
                        chart-series="dataCenterData.series"
                        chart-options="dataCenterData.options"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="dataCenterData in dataCenterDataList">
            <div class="row col-md-3">
                <canvas id="daily-chart-{{dataCenterData.dataCenter}}"
                    class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="dataCenterData.data"
                    chart-labels="dataCenterData.labels"
                    chart-series="dataCenterData.series"
                    chart-options="dataCenterData.options"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if this represents a bug in chart.js, but I'm trying to find a workaround, in any case.  I would think I'd want to render a thin "gutter" on the left side, but I don't understand how to make that happen.

**Update**:

I tried adding a "left-margin" or "left-padding" style like this:

```
            <div class="row" style="left-padding: 10">
```

It made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried using a css left-margin or left-padding?

Comment: Just did.  No difference.